# How to debug node js applications

Tags: mysql, javascript, node.js, debug

I have a nodeJS app It queries the Database(mysql) and makes certain API calls. On a load test two things happen:

1. It just stops responding for some users
2. The variables for some users are overwritten with the values of the some other users which either breaks the flow or the app crashes

I don't understand where the problem is. How can I debug it and fix the issues.

ps. It makes a certain amount of queries in a single run can that be a issue?

Comment: Since debugging is a developer task, would be better off looking on StackOverflow than here.    Here's one question very much like yours:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications

Comment: refer to this https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: The latest [VS Code supports node JS debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) out of the box.